# How to Calculate area of LULC at different elevation by using zonal statistics as table tool

Tags: arcmap, dem

I have to calculate the area of different land classes like forest,barren land etc from my classified land use data at different elevation zones at an interval of 100m. I have DEM of my study area also.

I have tried Zonal Statistisc as table tool and got the output table but i dont know how to identify the type of land class from the table. Can somebody give a solution?
[image][image]

Comment: Use [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to divide your DEM into elevation zones, then use Zonal statistics to get land class area per DEM zone.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but may i know how to identify land class type from the above table .I have uploaded screenshots of zonal table and my classified land type training set .How can i understand which land type is specified in each row in the table.I am new to arcgis .Can someone help me.

Comment: i have converted it into jpg format..is it visible now??

Comment: No i am just uploading the screeshot taken from my laptop.Cant upload a higher resolution image since max uploading file size limit is 2mb

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to get something like this:
[image]
    The codes are Corine Land Cover values, heights are in meters.

Expanding on BERA's answer I would approach this workflow like this:
1. Reclassify the DEM raster from exact elevation values to elevation classes based on 100m steps
2. Convert reclassified raster from raster to vector polygons
[image]
3. Convert the LandUse raster to polygon
[image]
4. Run Tabulate intersection on the two polygon layers giving the percentage of each Land Class in each elevation area.
[image]
5. Export the values to excel and build a nice 100% stacked bar graph.
Just use vlook-up to get the values for the clasess in order to get thea area for each class:
[image]